# For $\frac{k^p}{p^k}$ find all values $p$ for which the series converges absolutely

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k^p}{p^k}$$

This looks like a classic case of ratio test

$$\frac{(k+1)^p}{p^{k+1}}\frac{p^k}{k^p}$$

which simplifies to

$$\frac{(k+1)^p}{pk^p}$$

which simplifies to

$$\lim_{k \to \infty}\frac{1}{p} \Big(\frac{k+1}{k}\Big)^p \lt 1 $$

the inside becomes$$\frac{1+\frac{1}{k}}{k}$$

which becomes $0$ so moving the $p$ over we get $p \gt 0$

Comment: $\lim_{k \to \infty}\frac{1}{p} \Big(\frac{k+1}{k}\Big)^p=\frac1p$

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using ratio test, please don't forget the absolute values. What you want to evaluate is $$\lim_{k\to \infty} |\frac{(k+1)^p}{p^{k+1}}\frac{p^k}{k^p}|$$

Otherwise the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n$ with $\dfrac{x_{n+1}}{x^n}$ decreasing beyond all bounds as $n\to \infty$ would be absolutely convergent. Also, as pointed out in the comments, 
$$\lim_{k \to \infty}\frac{1}{p} \Big(\frac{k+1}{k}\Big)^p =\lim_{k \to \infty}\frac{1}{p} \Big(1+\frac{1}{k}\Big)^p=\frac1p$$

Although what you actually want is $$\lim_{k \to \infty}|\frac{1}{p} \Big(\frac{k+1}{k}\Big)^p|=\frac{1}{|p|}\lt 1$$
That is, $p\gt 1$ or $ p\lt -1$.